# Is the use of a verb as an adjective in 'scheduled date' acceptable?

Tags: past-participles

The word 'scheduled' is a verb.  Is it correct to say 'scheduled date'?  In this phrase the word scheduled is used as an adjective.  Date is when you meet someone who you are having romantic relationship with.

Comment: Just for your info, in this phrase, "date" could also refer to the calendar date of any scheduled event. For example, you could say, "I'm busy on the scheduled date of the meeting." For a romantic date, this phrase might be considered overly formal, even though it would be technically correct.

Answer (score 6):

This is an acceptable use.

*Scheduled* in this context is the past **participle** form of the verb *schedule*. Participles have that name because they may "participate" in two different word classes simultaneously. Past participles, specifically, may act as adjectives, with a passive sense: a "scheduled date" is a date which has been scheduled.